# Working with HDF4 file in GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, rasterio, hdf

I'm definitely not the most experienced GDAL user, but I already struggle for quite a while now getting my head around the `hdf4` file format in GDAL. The thing is that I have a directory with many `hdf4` files from Sentinel-2, all from the same day. In the end I want to build a mosaic of all the scenes. It's just that these scenes are from South Africa and when I create a VRT from all files and then use `gdal_translate` to make it a GeoTIFF it's all in the UTM zone 34N, what apparently doesn't make too much sense as it should be in 34S.

When I do `gdalinfo` on one of the `.hdf` files I get the following confusing output (sorry for the size of that):

```
gdalinfo HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf 
Driver: HDF4/Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
Files: HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  ACCODE=LaSRCS2AV3.5.5
  AngleBand=0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
  arop_ave_xshift(meters)=0
  arop_ave_yshift(meters)=0
  arop_ncp=0
  arop_rmse(meters)=0
  arop_s2_refimg=NONE
  cloud_coverage=1
  DATASTRIP_ID=S2B_OPER_MSI_L1C_DS_MPS__20181028T120816_S20181028T084332_N02.06
  HLS_PROCESSING_TIME=2018-11-01T23:32:43Z
  HORIZONTAL_CS_CODE=EPSG:32734
  HORIZONTAL_CS_NAME=WGS84 / UTM zone 34S
  L1C_IMAGE_QUALITY=NONE
  L1_PROCESSING_TIME=2018-10-28T12:47:06.529844Z
  MEAN_SUN_AZIMUTH_ANGLE(B01)=57.9076150593934
  MEAN_SUN_ZENITH_ANGLE(B01)=27.018691721451
  MEAN_VIEW_AZIMUTH_ANGLE(B01)=177.57328049295
  MEAN_VIEW_ZENITH_ANGLE(B01)=3.06199611054485
  MSI band 01 bandpass adjustment slope and offset=0.995900, -0.000200
  MSI band 02 bandpass adjustment slope and offset=0.977800, -0.004000
  MSI band 03 bandpass adjustment slope and offset=1.007500, -0.000800
  MSI band 04 bandpass adjustment slope and offset=0.976100, 0.001000
  MSI band 11 bandpass adjustment slope and offset=1.000000, -0.000300
  MSI band 12 bandpass adjustment slope and offset=0.986700, 0.000400
  MSI band 8a bandpass adjustment slope and offset=0.996600, 0.000000
  NBAR_Solar_Zenith=43.7861821326806
  NCOLS=3660
  NROWS=3660
  PROCESSING_BASELINE=02.06
  PRODUCT_URI=S2B_MSIL1C_20181028T082039_N0206_R121_T34JDN_20181028T120816.SAFE
  SENSING_TIME=2018-10-28T08:43:32.629Z
  SPACECRAFT_NAME=Sentinel-2B
  spatial_coverage=100
  SPATIAL_RESOLUTION=30
  TILE_ID=S2B_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MPS__20181028T120816_A008584_T34JDN_N02.06
  ULX=399960
  ULY=-3199980
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B01
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[3660x3660] B01 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B02
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[3660x3660] B02 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B03
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[3660x3660] B03 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B04
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[3660x3660] B04 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B05
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[3660x3660] B05 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B06
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[3660x3660] B06 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B07
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[3660x3660] B07 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_8_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B08
  SUBDATASET_8_DESC=[3660x3660] B08 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_9_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B8A
  SUBDATASET_9_DESC=[3660x3660] B8A Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_10_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B09
  SUBDATASET_10_DESC=[3660x3660] B09 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_11_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B10
  SUBDATASET_11_DESC=[3660x3660] B10 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_12_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B11
  SUBDATASET_12_DESC=[3660x3660] B11 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_13_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:B12
  SUBDATASET_13_DESC=[3660x3660] B12 Grid (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_14_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf":Grid:QA
  SUBDATASET_14_DESC=[3660x3660] QA Grid (8-bit unsigned integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Could someone who has a little more experience in working with this file format give a hint on what to do with that?

I used python, and my commands were: `build_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT("final.vrt", "HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf ") final_tif = gdal.Translate("final.tiff", "final.vrt")`

Comment: Please, include the commands used.

Comment: The comment is:

`gdalinfo HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf`

Comment: Hi Robin, please include in the post the commands used to create VRT and GeoTIFF files.

Comment: Oh yes of course, sorry: 
I used python, and my commands were: 


`build_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT("final.vrt", "HLS.S30.T34JDN.2018301.v1.4.hdf ")`            

`final_tif = gdal.Translate("final.tiff", "final.vrt")`

Comment: Can you provide the output of running gdalinfo on your final tiff?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the use of HDF format with GDAL the key concept is that the file contains subdatasets as opposed to raster bands.

With a GeoTiff, for example, you can open it, and pick a band to read

```
f = ''
ds = gdal.Open(f)

if ds is None:
    raise Exception('Failed to open dataset')
b = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# etc...
```

When using a HDF file, the file itself does not contain raster bands - it's only really a pointer to the subdatasets within. To interrogate a subdataset, it first has to be opened, similar to above.

```
f = ''
ds = gdal.Open(f) # ds is now the HDF file

# Error catching here..

print(ds.GetMetdata()) # This will print the metadata you see in your gdalinfo output

# The GetSubDatasets method returns a list of all the subdatasets in the HDF file
# Each element is a tuple object of the form (subdataset_path,subdataset_desc)
sds_list = ds.GetSubDatasets()

# Let's see what the subdatasets are...
for sds in sds_list:
    print(sds[1]) # i.e. the desc

# Say the first subdataset corresponds to reflectance in the blue band and we now
# want to access the data. We open the subdataset as we would any other dataset
blue_sds = sds_list[0] # this is a tuple (path,desc)
blue = gdal.Open(blue_sds[0]) # open using the path

prj = blue.GetProjection()
bnd = blue.GetRasterBand(1)

# etc...
```